# print "msg" on Dosbox through nasm .asm file

Tags: assembly, nasm

Following is the code that calculate the length of string and then print it in dosbox using nasm assembly language but it is giving logical error and im stuck after running it on dosbox and then i have to re-open it inorder to run the .asm file again
Following is the code
org 0x0100
jmp start

msg: db "Aurangzaib Awan", 0
msgLen: dw 0

; Clear screen subroutine
clrscreen:
push es
push ax
push cx
push di

```
mov ax, 0x0b800
mov es, ax
mov ax, 0x0720
mov cx, 2000
rep stosw

pop di
pop cx
pop ax
pop es
ret
```

; Subroutine to calculate the length of a string
cal_Len:
push bp
mov bp, sp
push ax
push cx
push si
push di

```
mov di, [bp + 4]
mov cx, 0xffff   ; load a big num in cx
xor al, al
repne scasb
mov ax, 0xffff
sub ax, cx
dec ax
mov word [msgLen], ax

pop di
pop si
pop cx
pop ax
pop ax
pop bp
ret 2
```

; Subroutine to print a string
mystr:
push bp
mov bp, sp
push es
push ax
push cx
push si
push di

```
mov ax, 0xb800
mov es, ax
mov ax, 80
mul byte [bp + 6] ; y pos
add ax, [bp + 8]  ; x pos
mov di, ax
mov si, [bp + 10]
mov cx, [msgLen]
mov ax, [bp + 4]  ; attribute
cld

nextChar:
    lodsb
    stosw
    loop nextChar

pop di
pop si
pop cx
pop ax
pop ax
pop es
pop bp
ret 10
```

start:
call clrscreen
mov ax, msg
push ax
call cal_Len
mov ax, msg
push ax
mov ax, 30       ; x pos
push ax
mov ax, 20       ; y pos
push ax
mov ax, 1          ; attribute
push ax
call mystr

```
    mov ax, 0x4c00
    int 0x21
```

i just want it print the msg on dosbox

Answer (score 1):

### The program is easy to fix

Here's a list of the errors:

- Both the *cal_Len* and the *mystr* routines have a `pop ax` too many.
- The *mystr* routine, that has **4** word-sized arguments, should return via `ret 8` instead of `ret 10`.
- The attribute in *mystr* gets overwritten by the `lodsb` instruction that loads the AL register. Move the attribute to AH: `mov ah, [bp+4]`.
- The address calculation for the video buffer needs to double the value because for every character cell in the text screen **2** bytes are used: `mov di, ax` `add di, ax`.